# SBT Triggered Execution symbol Issue

Tags: cmd, sbt

I want to run the **compile** instruction in SBT from cmd as triggered execution with the symbol `~`, but it doesn't work.

I added to the `sbtconfig.txt` the extra option

```
-Dinput.encoding=Cp1252
```

but it still doesn't work.

Sbt version 0.14.0

My OS is WIN 7.

Thanks!